# Keyboard shortcut to move tabs left or right?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, high-sierra, automation

Is there a Safari keyboard shortcut to move a tab?

If not, how can I make one?

I wouldn't even know how to write an AppleScript for this, the only method I see of moving tabs is to drag them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two AppleScripts for moving tabs one position right or left. The AppleScript gets the current tab index, checks if it can be moved, then moves it and ensures it's still active. This does refresh the page though but this appears to be a limitation of the AppleScript since it uses the Standard Suite's move.

- Move tab one to the right

  ```
  tell application "Safari" to tell front window
      set currentindex to index of current tab
      if currentindex is equal to number of tabs then return
      move tab currentindex to after tab (currentindex + 1)
      set current tab to tab (currentindex + 1)
  end tell
  ```
- Move tab one to the left

  ```
  tell application "Safari Technology Preview" to tell front window
      set currentindex to index of current tab
      if currentindex is 1 then return
      move tab currentindex to before tab (currentindex - 1)
      set current tab to tab (currentindex - 1)
  end tell
  ```

You can assign keyboard shortcuts to these by creating a service to run these scripts and assigning a shortcut to the service, or with a third-party app.

Comment: Pretty good, but as you say it refresh the page. Nice trick though!

Comment: do you think that this might be possible to do generically, not only for safari? Like tell front application, rather than tell Safari ... thanks!

Comment: Also, would be good with a module total windows, that would move it to first if at last and last if at first and moved left.

Comment: I am working on it, but I have never played with applescripts :S